# how create dynamic multiple jqgrid some page

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I want create dynamic multiple jqgrid .but create one jqgrid
first dynamic this down html

```
<div dir='rtl' align='center' class='table - responsive'><div class='row well'>
            <table id='dataArray' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'></table> 
            <div id="pager_dataArray"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div dir='rtl' align='center' class='table - responsive'>
                <div class='row well'>
                    <table id='dataArray2' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'></table>
                    <div id="pager_dataArray2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

then use js code for create jqgrid  ;plase pay attention iam for get model and header grid call function  in js file,

> LoadGrid()
>
> data: LoadGrid(),
> colNames: getColNames(LoadGrid()[0]),
> colModel: getColModels(LoadGrid()[0]),

```js
var searchOptions = ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'in', 'ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'];
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var today = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
        (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
        (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day;

    $("#dynamicGrouping").change(function () {
        var groupingName = $(this).val();
        alert(groupingName)
        if (groupingName) {
            //$('#list').jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', ['AddDate_D', 'Name_c']);
             $('#' + gridid).jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', [groupingName]);
        } else {
             $('#' + gridid).jqGrid('groupingRemove');
        }
    });
  
        caption: "تست گرید",
    $('#' + gridid).jqGrid({
        caption: "تست گرید",
        //url from which data should be requested
        // url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Home")',      
        datatype: 'local',
        //این تابع از فایل androidfunction فراخوانی می شود
        data: LoadGrid(),
        colNames: getColNames(LoadGrid()[0]),
        colModel: getColModels(LoadGrid()[0]),
        jsonReader: {
            root: "Rows",
            page: "Page",
            total: "Total",
            records: "Records",
            repeatitems: true,
            userdata: "UserData",
            id: "Id",
            cell: "RowCells"
        },
        grouping: true,
        iconSet: "glyphIcon",
        groupingView: {
            //   groupField: ['AddDate_D' , 'Name_c'],
            groupColumnShow: [true],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            groupCollapse: true,
            groupOrder: ['asc'],
            groupSummary: [true]
        },
        cmTemplate: { editable: false, autoResizable: true },
        toppager: true,
        // groupingView: { groupField: ['AddDate_D'] },
        mtype: 'POST',
        footerrow: true,
        // userDataOnFooter : true,
        //gridComplete: function () {
        //    var $grid = $("#FooTable");
        //    var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Price_Num', false, 'sum');
        //    $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { price: colSum });
        //},
        pager: $('#' + pagegrid),
        //number of rows per page
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        //initial sorting column
        sortname: 'Id',
        //initial sorting direction
        sortorder: 'asc',
        // loadonce: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        //we want to display total records count
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        hidegrid: false,
        direction: "rtl",
        gridview: true,
        altRows: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        autoencode: true,
        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
        ExpandColClick: true,
        //   ignoreCase: true,
        //loadComplete : function() {
        //    var table = this;
        //    setTimeout(function(){
        //        updatePagerIcons(table);
        //    }, 0);
        //},
        loadComplete: function () {
            sumarValores($(this))
        },
        loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
            jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        },
    })
        .navGrid(
                       $('#' + pagegrid),
                     //enabling buttons
                     { add: false, del: false, edit: false, search: false },
                     //edit option
                     {
                         width: 'auto', checkOnUpdate: true, checkOnSubmit: true,
                         beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                             centerDialog(form,  $('#' + gridid));
                         }
                     },
                     //add options
                     {
                         width: 'auto', url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct","Home")',
                     },
                      //add options

                     //delete options
                     {
                         url: '@Url.Action("DeleteProduct","Home")', reloadAfterSubmit: false
                     })

                 .jqGrid('inlineNav', $('#' + pagegrid),
                 {
                     // cloneToTop: true,
                     edit: false, add: true, save: false, cancel: false,
                     edittext: "ویرایش", addtext: "جدید", savetext: "ذخیره", canceltext: "لغو",
                     addParams: {
                         // اگر می‌خواهید ردیف‌های جدید در ابتدا ظاهر شوند، این سطر را حذف کنید
                         position: "first", //ردیف‌های جدید در آخر ظاهر می‌شوند
                         rowID: '_empty',
                         useDefValues: true,
                         addRowParams: getInlineNavParams(true)
                     },
                     editParams: getInlineNavParams(false)
                 }

                 )

     $('#' + gridid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#list_toppager',
    {
        caption: ""/*"Show"*/, buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink", title: "Show Link",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var grid =  $('#' + gridid);
            var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            window.location = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'dataUrl');
        }
    });

     $('#' + gridid).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        stringResult: true,//// وجود این سطر سبب می‌شود تا اپراتورها به سرور ارسال شوند
        enableClear: false,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        searchOperators: true, // فعال سازی منوی اپراتورها
        defaultSearch: "cn"

    });

    function getSelectedRow() {
        var grid =  $('#' + gridid);
        var rowKey = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', "selrow");

        if (rowKey)
            alert("Selected row primary key is: " + rowKey);
        else
            alert("No rows are selected");
    }
});

function sumarValores($self) {
    var sumaHa = 0;
    var columnNames = $('#' + gridid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');
    var global;
    var footer = {};
    for (var z = 0; z < columnNames.length; z++) {
        var colN = columnNames[z];

        //    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", footer);

        if (colN == "Price") {
            colN = colN.concat('_Num');
            var sumtotal = $self.jqGrid("getCol", colN, false, "sum");
            //   global =  colN;
            global = 'Price_Num';
            footer[global] = sumtotal;
            //$self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
            //  Price_Num: sumtotal,              
            //});
            $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", footer);
            break;
        }
        if (colN == "AddDate") {
            global = 'AddDate_D';

            var sumtotald = $self.jqGrid("getCol", colN, false, "sum");
            // footer[global] = sumtotald;
            $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set",
            {
                AddDate_D: sumtotald,
            }
        );
        }
    }


}

function getInlineNavParams(isAdd) {
    return {
        // استفاده از آدرس‌های مختلف برای حالات ویرایش و ثبت اطلاعات جدید
        url: isAdd ? '@Url.Action("AddUser", "Home")' : '@Url.Action("EditUser","Home")',
        key: true,
        restoreAfterError: false, // این مورد سبب می‌شود تا اعتبارسنجی سمت سرور قابل اعمال شود
        oneditfunc: function (rowId) {
            // نمایش دکمه‌های ذخیره و لغو داخل همان سطر
            $("#jSaveButton_" + rowId).show();
            $("#jCancelButton_" + rowId).show();
        },
        successfunc: function () {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid"); // دریافت کلید اصلی ردیف از سرور
            }, 50);
        },
        errorfunc: function (rowid, response, stat) {
            if (stat != 'error') // this.Response.StatusCode == 200
                return;

            var result = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            if (result.success === false) {
                //نمایش خطای اعتبار سنجی سمت سرور پس از ویرایش یا افزودن
                $.jgrid.info_dialog($.jgrid.errors.errcap,
                    '<div class="ui-state-error">' + result.message + '</div>',
                    $.jgrid.edit.bClose,
                    { buttonalign: 'center' });
            }
        }
    };
}
function centerDialog(form, grid) {
    var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + grid[0].id);
    var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent(); // div#gbox_list
    var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
    var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
    var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
    var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
    var parentTop = parentDiv.offset().top;
    var parentLeft = parentDiv.offset().left;
    dlgDiv[0].style.top = Math.round(parentTop + (parentHeight - dlgHeight) / 2) + "px";
    dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round(parentLeft + (parentWidth - dlgWidth) / 2) + "px";
}

function getColNames(data, status) {
    var keys = [];
    if (status != 'headr') {
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push((key.split('_'))[0]);
            }
        }
        keys.push('');
    }
    else {
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key);
            }

        }
        keys.push('');
    }
    return keys;
}
function getColModels(data) {
    var colNames = getColNames(data, 'headr');
    var colModelsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++) {
        var str;
        if (i === 0) {
            str = {
                name: (colNames[i]),
                index: (colNames[i]),
                key: true,
                editable: false,
                search: false,
                width: 20,


            };
        } else if (i >= 1 && i <= colNames.length - 2) {
            switch ((colNames[i].split('_'))[1]) {
                case ('Num'):
                    str = {
                        name: (colNames[i]),
                        index: (colNames[i]),
                        editable: true,
                        summaryType: 'sum', summaryTpl: '<b>جمع مشاهدات: {0}</b>',

                        //width: 100,
                        searchoptions: { sopt: searchOptions },
                        formatter: 'currency',
                        formatoptions:
                          {
                              decimalSeparator: '.',
                              thousandsSeparator: ',',
                              decimalPlaces: 0,
                              prefix: 'ريال'
                          },
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',

                        // summaryType: function (val, name, record) {
                    };
                    // tt = 'Price_Num';

                    break;
                case ('D'):
                    str = {
                        name: (colNames[i]),
                        index: (colNames[i]),
                        editable: true,
                        // width: 100,
                        searchoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                $(elem).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'm/d/y',
                                    onClose: function (event) {
                                         $('#' + gridid).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
                                    }
                                });


                                //    datepicker({
                                //    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                                //    changeYear: true,
                                //    changeMonth: true,
                                //    showWeek: true,
                                //    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                //        setTimeout(function () {
                                //             $('#' + gridid)[0].triggerToolbar();
                                //        }, 100);
                                //    }
                                //});

                            },
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                $(elem).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'm/d/y',
                                    onClose: function (event) {
                                         $('#' + gridid).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 2 }]);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            , sopt: searchOptions
                        },
                        editoptions: {
                            maxlength: 10,
                            onclick: 'PersianDatePicker.Show(this,' + '1395/02/01' + ')'
                        },
                        editrules: {
                            required: true
                        }

                    };
                    break;
                case ('c'):
                    str = {
                        name: (colNames[i]),
                        index: (colNames[i]),
                        editable: true,
                        //width:100,
                        searchoptions: { sopt: searchOptions },


                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    // alert('>41');
            }

        }
        else {
            str = {
                name: 'myac',
                index: colNames[i],

                resize: false,
                fixed: true, sortable: false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                search: false,
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true
                },

            }

        }
        //formatter: 'currency',
        //formatoptions:
        //{
        //    decimalSeparator: '.',
        //    thousandsSeparator: ',',
        //    decimalPlaces: 2,
        //    prefix: '$'
        //},
        //editable: true, edittype: 'text',

        colModelsArray.push(str);
    }

    return colModelsArray;
}

function updatePagerIcons(table) {
    //var replacement =
    //{
    //    'ui-icon-seek-first': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140',
    //    'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-140',
    //    'ui-icon-seek-next': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-140',
    //    'ui-icon-seek-end': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140'
    //};
    //$('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function () {
    //    var icon = $(this);
    //    var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));

    //    if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
    //})
}
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
function LoadGrid() {
    object = {
        "dataArray":
            [
                 { id_R: 1, Name_c: "dummy1", AddDate_D: "1394/07/27", Price_Num: "10000" },
                 { id_R: 2, Name_c: "dummy2", AddDate_D: "1394/07/28", Price_Num: "120000" },
            ],
        "dataArray2":
        [
            { id_R: 9, Name2_c: "dummy9", AddDate2_D: "1393/04/28", Price2_Num: "200000" },
            { id_R: 10, Name_c: "dummy10", AddDate_D: "1393/04/04", Price_Num: "2100000" },
       
        ]
    };

      // برای  مپ کردن ارایه یه ارایه دیگر
     //departement = $.map(dataArray, function (value, index) {
     //   return [value];
     //});  
     var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
      // var names = 'grd1'
     var col = [];
     var gridarr = [];
     var pagegrarr = [];
     //مقادیر ارایه را در متغیر زیر می ریزد
     var col = Object.values(object);

    //تعداد ارایه برای گرید بدست اوردیم
     var countarr = col.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < countarr; i++) {
         //اسم جدول گرید
         gridarr[i] = names[i];
         pagegrarr[i] = 'pager_' + names[i];
       //  return col[i];
     }
     flag++;

     switch (flag) {
         case 1:
         case 2:
         case 3:
         case 4:
             gridid = gridarr[0]
             pagegrid = pagegrarr[0]
             return col[0];
             break;
         case 5:
         case 6:
         case 7:
         case 8:
             gridid = gridarr[1]
             pagegrid = pagegrarr[1]
             return col[1];
             break;
      
         default:
             break;
    }  
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function grid(tt) {
                //=== LOCA VARIABLES ===//$.jgrid.randId()
                var myGrid = $("<table>").attr("id", tt);
                var myPager = $("<div>").attr("id", tt +"_pager");
                var localData1 = {
                    "page": 1,
                    "totalRecords": 5,
                    "pageSize": 3,
                    "rows": [
                    { Name: "Name 1" },
                    { Name: "Name 3" },
                    { Name: "Name 2" }
                    ]
                };

                function publicInit() {
                    $("body").append(myGrid, myPager);
                    myGrid.jqGrid({
                        pager: myPager,
                        data: localData1.rows,
                        datatype: "local",
                        colModel: [
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: "500" }
                        ],
                        //localReader: {
                        //    repeatitems: false
                       // },
                       // rowNum: 3,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        height: "auto",
                        ignoreCase: true
                    });
                }
                //=== REVEALING PATTERN===//
                return {
                    init: publicInit
                }
            };

            var grid1 = new grid("y");
            grid1.init();

            $("body").append("<br><br>"); //Add some spacing to distinguish between both grids

            var grid2 = new grid("c");
            grid2.init();

            $("body").append("<br><br>"); //Add some spacing to distinguish between both grids

            var grid2 = new grid("b");
            grid2.init();

        });
    </script>
```